# Google maps api, "couldn't get connection factory client"

Tags: android, google-maps

When I port my app which uses a google maps, all that displays is a grid and not a location map. How do I fix this? 
We have registered the project in the Google APIs console online, as well as gotten a key from eclipse and checked that they all matched up. (we turned on "Google Maps Android API v2" and "Google Maps API v3")
We also checked all the permissions according to the official android tutorial.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.soconnection"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />


        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.crap"
            android:value="crap" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.soconnection.FullscreenActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity
            android:name="com.example.soconnection.WebActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_web" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.soconnection.Webactivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_webactivity" >
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Logcat:

```
01-30 16:41:40.166: W/MapActivity(11548): Recycling dispatcher android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher@41731250
01-30 16:41:40.166: V/MapActivity(11548): Recycling map object.
01-30 16:41:40.256: I/MapActivity(11548): Handling network change notification:CONNECTED
01-30 16:41:40.256: E/MapActivity(11548): Couldn't get connection factory client
01-30 16:41:40.716: W/System.err(11548): IOException processing: 26
01-30 16:41:40.716: W/System.err(11548): java.io.IOException: Server returned: 3
01-30 16:41:40.716: W/System.err(11548):    at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.BaseTileRequest.readResponseData(BaseTileRequest.java:115)
01-30 16:41:40.716: W/System.err(11548):    at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.MapService$MapTileRequest.readResponseData(MapService.java:1473)
01-30 16:41:40.716: W/System.err(11548):    at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.processDataRequest(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1117)
01-30 16:41:40.716: W/System.err(11548):    at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.serviceRequests(DataRequestDispatcher.java:994)
01-30 16:41:40.716: W/System.err(11548):    at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher$DispatcherServer.run(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1702)
01-30 16:41:40.716: W/System.err(11548):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

And then the lines "java.io.IOException: Server Returned: 3" to the end just keeps repeating a bunch of times.

Comment: Your title seems to imply that an error occurred when trying to load the map. Would you post the entirety of the error that showed up in your logcat?

Comment: Yes the map loaded but it is just brown tiles, no geogrpahical features or anything..

Comment: Your `AndroidManifest.xml` is set up as if you are using Maps V2 (which I presume is your intent), but `MapActivity` is only available in Maps V1 as far as I can tell (correct me if I'm wrong). Are you sure you're actually using the Maps V2 APIs?

Comment: Yes I concur the manifest is not right  you should also have <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"

Comment: Oh. I want to use v2. I never enabled v1 (never knew how to...) 
Btw I already have that line, is it supposed to say API_KEY or the api key that I got from the website? (i posted it as com.google.android.maps.v2.crap)